# how do I pass variables between functions?

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, scope

Good afternoon, friends. I have two questions.

1. How can I pass Fulloffset to the scrollToRef function?
2. How can I declare props in an object so that they are available in all functions? I'm trying to avoid declaring something like "const { arrayOfHeight } = this.props" in every function

```js
export function withScrollToFirstError(Component: t.form.Component): React.ComponentType {
  class ScrollToFirstErrorHOC extends PureComponent<OuterProps & PropsFromState, ComponentState> {
    constructor(props: OuterProps & PropsFromState) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        height: 0,
        offset: 0,
      };
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      this.existError();
    }

    existError = () => {
      const { currentFieldId, firstFieldId, arrayOfHeight, fieldOffset, fieldErrors } = this.props;
      this.calculateCoordinate();
    };

    calculateCoordinate = () => {
        const fullOffset = offset + fieldOffset[0];
      this.scrollToRef();
    };

    scrollToRef = () => {
      if (this.props.reference) {
        this.props.reference.current.scrollTo({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          animated: true,
        });
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Fulloffset to the scrollToRef

```
calculateCoordinate = () => {
      const fullOffset = offset + fieldOffset[0];
      this.scrollToRef(fullOffset); // like this
    };

scrollToRef = (fullOffset) => {
      if (this.props.reference) {
        this.props.reference.current.scrollTo({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          animated: true,
        });
      }
    };
```

Declare props globally

```
export function withScrollToFirstError(Component: t.form.Component): React.ComponentType {
  class ScrollToFirstErrorHOC extends PureComponent<OuterProps & PropsFromState, ComponentState> {
    constructor(props: OuterProps & PropsFromState) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        height: 0,
        offset: 0,
      };
     // initialize here
     this.arrayOfHeight = props.arrayOfHeight;
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      this.existError();
    }

    existError = () => {
      // use here like 
      this.arrayOfHeight;
    };
}
```